# Accessing the Type Definition at cursor position?

Tags: monaco-editor

We have a custom API which we provide to the Monaco editor instance within our app.  Alongside our custom API is documentation.  A feature which would benefit users greatly would be the ability to open the context menu and select "View API Documentation":

[image: View API Documentation]

The intention would be to parse the comment of this object for a unique ID that we could then use to open the documentation.

The action handling provides a `run(editor: editor.ICodeEditor) => {}`, however I can't seem to find a published way to retrieve the definition (if even possible).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the type definition. It's created and kept in the language server code for the active language.

Instead just get the line from the cursor and parse it yourself to find out what it refers to.